# Uniform Distibution Over Middle-Third Cantor Set (and Its Approximates)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, probability-limit-theorems

[image: S1 Q2.7]

Above is my question. I have done part 1, but I am unsure how to do the next part(s). Part 2 at least doesn't look that difficult, but I can't get the specifics. My main issue is that I can't get a particularly clean representation of $C_n$. A slight hint would be most appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: It may be useful in getting a recursive description of $F_n$ to note that for $n\ge 1$ you can write $$C_n=\frac13C_{n-1}\cup\left(\frac13C_{n-1}+\frac23\right)\;.$$

Comment: Ah yes, a recursive definition of $C_n$ as well, that's very helpful, thanks. I'll let you know how I get on with that. :)

Comment: I am rather struggling with getting the recursive description... any hint? :P

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that *distribution function* here means *cumulative distribution function* (as suggested by $(3)$)?

Comment: Yep. $F_X(x) = \Bbb P(X \le x).$

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, you get $$F_n(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac12F_{n-1}(3x),&\text{if }0\le x\le\frac13\\\\
\frac12,&\text{if }\frac13<x<\frac23\\\\
\frac12+\frac12F_{n-1}(3x-2),&\text{if }\frac23\le x\le 1\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Hm, ok, thanks. To be honest, I can't quite see why currently, but I'll have a think about it. Seems too simple to me... but I can see why it would be only three cases... Thanks, I'll work with that and hopefully get somewhere! :)

Comment: The first third of $F_n$ has to look like all of $F_{n-1}$, but compressed horizontally by a factor of $\frac13$ and vertically by a factor of $\frac12$: that’s what the $3$ in $3x$ and the coefficient $\frac12$ in the first clause do. The third clause is basically the same thing all over again, but $\frac12$ higher.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see. Thanks very much. Hopefully I'll be able to do something with it now! It's the last question on my example sheet, so not supposed to be easy! Haha! =P

Comment: You’re welcome; good luck with it!